# SVG animated circles to the center vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animate

I am trying to create an SVG loading placeholder and I want to place the 3 animated **circles to the center vertically and horizontally** in the rectangle without overlapping each other. I tried putting them in a `g` and applying `width` and `margin` using CSS but that did not work. Is there a way to achieve it?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="200" viewBox="0 0 500 100">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#f3f3f3"/>
      <circle fill="#2FC143" stroke="none" cx="6" cy="50" r="6">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="1s" type="translate" values="0 15 ; 0 -15; 0 15" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.1"></animateTransform>
      </circle>
      <circle fill="#2FC143" stroke="none" cx="30" cy="50" r="6">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="1s" type="translate" values="0 10 ; 0 -10; 0 10" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.2"></animateTransform>
      </circle>
      <circle fill="#2FC143" stroke="none" cx="54" cy="50" r="6">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="1s" type="translate" values="0 5 ; 0 -5; 0 5" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.3"></animateTransform>
      </circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

I would simplify the SVG and use css to lay out where/how the SVG sits within its parent container.

Also, if you use currentColor in the SVG fill attributes, the color will be inherited.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.svg-wrapper {
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 300px;
}

svg {
  width: 60px;
  color: #2FC143;
}

.secondary {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}

.secondary svg {
  color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-wrapper">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 60 42">
      <circle fill="currentColor" stroke="none" cx="6" cy="21" r="6">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="1s" type="translate" values="0 15 ; 0 -15; 0 15" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.1"></animateTransform>
      </circle>
      <circle fill="currentColor" stroke="none" cx="30" cy="21" r="6">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="1s" type="translate" values="0 10 ; 0 -10; 0 10" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.2"></animateTransform>
      </circle>
      <circle fill="currentColor" stroke="none" cx="54" cy="21" r="6">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="1s" type="translate" values="0 5 ; 0 -5; 0 5" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.3"></animateTransform>
      </circle>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="svg-wrapper secondary">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 60 42">
      <circle fill="currentColor" stroke="none" cx="6" cy="21" r="6">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="1s" type="translate" values="0 15 ; 0 -15; 0 15" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.1"></animateTransform>
      </circle>
      <circle fill="currentColor" stroke="none" cx="30" cy="21" r="6">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="1s" type="translate" values="0 10 ; 0 -10; 0 10" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.2"></animateTransform>
      </circle>
      <circle fill="currentColor" stroke="none" cx="54" cy="21" r="6">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="1s" type="translate" values="0 5 ; 0 -5; 0 5" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.3"></animateTransform>
      </circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Without CSS you can use `preserveAspectRatio`

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 42" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" width="500" height="400">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#f3f3f3"/>
      <circle fill="currentColor" stroke="none" cx="6" cy="21" r="6">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="1s" type="translate" values="0 15 ; 0 -15; 0 15" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.1"></animateTransform>
      </circle>
      <circle fill="currentColor" stroke="none" cx="30" cy="21" r="6">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="1s" type="translate" values="0 10 ; 0 -10; 0 10" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.2"></animateTransform>
      </circle>
      <circle fill="currentColor" stroke="none" cx="54" cy="21" r="6">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="1s" type="translate" values="0 5 ; 0 -5; 0 5" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.3"></animateTransform>
      </circle>
  </svg>
```

Comment: I think the minimum viewBox height that can be done with the animation and radius is 42, the animation is cut off a bit in this code snippet. Also the xmnls attributes can be removed completely since it's inline SVG and not being used as an image.

Comment: Thanks @JHeth updated with your suggestions

Comment: @ksav I am using the LiteSpeed Webserver plugin which allows only inline SVG. I do not have an option to wrap it with HTML. Thank you though.